# Change tooltip data in Google Charts

Tags: charts, tooltip

I have column google charts. (using https://www.google.com/jsapi)

Vertical axis for count of bananas(for example)
Horizontal axis for dates

so, each my column tooltip looks like:

```
20.02.2011
Bananas: 3
```

I need to replace 20.02.2011 on some my text on each column.

Is it possible?

**UPD**
I need to replace 20.02.2011 on some my text on each column.
But dates on Horizontal axis should stay as they are.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it without changing your actual data points is via the tooltip option. As an example copy the following code to google's visualization playground.

```
function drawVisualization() {
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable()
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number');
    data.addColumn({type:'string',role:'tooltip'});
    data.addRow();
    base = 10;
    data.setValue(0, 0, 'Datapoint1');
    data.setValue(0, 1, base++);
    data.setValue(0, 2, " This is my tooltip1 ");

    data.addRow();
    data.setValue(1, 0, 'Datapoint2');
    data.setValue(1, 1, base++);
    data.setValue(1, 2, "This is my second tooltip2");

    // Draw the chart.
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, {legend:'none', width:600, height:400});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change the horizontal axis with the text that you want.

For ex.
In this sample code http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#bar_chart
[Chart URL](http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/retrieve_cache?unique_id=http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/samples/boilerplateHTML/visualization/barchart.html%7Chttp://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/samples/js/visualization/barchart.js&defaultSample=true)

If you want to replace year with your custom text then change

```
var years = [2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008];
```

to either

```
var years = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
```

or

```
var years = ["2003:a", "2004:b", "2005:c", "2006:d", "2007:e", "2008:f"];
```